# Select many columns and a column with condition from another column

Tags: sql-server, select

I have this table for example:

| ID | name | city | cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alpha | dola | du |
| 2 | beta | mola | su |
| 3 | zeta | dola | hu |

Desired outcome:

select all Ids, all names, but only data from column cats where column city = 'dola', otherwise blank

Comment: So what is your question? What have *you* tried to solve the problem? Why didn't said attempts work? [so] is *not* a free coding service; don't treat it like one. I suggest you read the [tour] (you were prompted to when you signed up, and didn't), and have a read of [ask].

Comment: obviously im new to the site (as a user) without any coding background. I wasnt seeking a free coding, just wanted a hint where to start (after half an hour googling).. I get it but such a website is giving us -non coders- a chance to start!! cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above version, You can use [**`IIF()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT Id, Name, IIF(City = 'dola', Cat, '') AS Cat
FROM yourTable
```

You can also use [**`CASE Statement`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT Id, Name, Case When City = 'dola' Then Cat ELSE '' END AS Cat
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: first one is more elegant. It also took less time (43s vs 80s). Thanks!...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.ID,T.NAME,
CASE
  WHEN T.CITY='DOLA' THEN T.CAT
 ELSE ''
END AS XX 
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
```

Do you need this one?

Comment: DOLA should be lower case

Answer (score -1):

Assuming name of table is Table1 You can try the following query

```
SELECT A.ID, A.name, B.City, B.cat
from Table1 A
Left Outer Join Table1 B
ON A.ID=B.ID AND B.city='dola';
```

Comment: Although this works (on the reasonable presumption that id,city is unique), using a LEFT JOIN is extremely expensive, especially when all it needs is a scalar expression, such as with CASE.